# aborting a git merge and going back to uncommitted work

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, git-stash

this is my situation:

i forgot to pull and I started working on my project. what I worked on this morning is totally different from my last commit on that repository.

I'm doing a commit and I'm prompted to pull, this is when i realized i will have an avalanche of unresolvable conflicts.

i pull and my project is all messed up now.
is there a way to going back to the work i did before performing the pull?

not reverting to my last commit because I would lose all the work i did today, but just stash all the mess and go back to 5 minutes ago?

Comment: Maybe you should post the output of `git status`, so we can get an overview of the situation.

Comment: Oh, and you don't get a prompt to pull after committing. This happens only when you push.

Comment: @BeatBolli i know the files which have conflicts. the problem is that they're very difficult to resolve. that's why i want go back to the uncommitted work :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, abort the unfinished merge:

```
git merge --abort
```

Then, undo your last commit (the one that leads to the conflicts):

```
git reset HEAD^
```

This leaves the changes that you did in the commit in the worktree, so you can just go on editing.

Comment: git merge --abort worked! I'm now back to what i worked on this morning. should i git reset HEAD^ as well? could you explain this part a bit more? i don't want to mess this up :)

Comment: You have three possibilities now: `git reset HEAD^` do undo just the commit; add more changes and do `git commit --amend` to change the last commit; or add more changes and commit them separately.

Comment: `git reset HEAD^` simply deletes the commit, but leaves the changes that you committed in the source code.